# laplacian and signless laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Let $L(G)$ and $Q(G)$ be the Laplacian matrix and Signless laplacian matrix for a graph $G$.
By definition, $L(G) = D(G)-A(G)$ and $Q(G) = D(G) + A(G)$, where $D(G)$ is the degree matrix for $G$ and $A(G)$ be its adjacency matrix.
My doubt is that, “Does $L(G)$ and $Q(G)$ have the same properties for any graph $G$?”

Comment: What do you mean by "have the same properties"? They're not the same matrix for any graph that has edges.

Comment: The matrices are both useful in the study of the structure of a graph but they behave differently of course. One example is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ :
for any graph, the multiplicity of 0 as an eigenvalue of the
signless Laplacian is equal to the number of bipartite components, while it is the number of connected component for the (usual) Laplacian. One can easily find a graph where these are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are considering an arbitrary graph $G$, then the only similarity that jumps out to me is that the trace of $L(G)$ and the trace of $Q(G)$ are both equal to twice the number of edges of $G$. But this is pretty boring since it's just an artifact of the trace of the adjacency matrix being zero (for simple graphs at least) and hence  $\text{tr}(L(G)) = \text{tr}(Q(G)) = \text{tr}(D(G))$.

But, if we restrict ourselves and consider any *bipartite* graph $G$, magic happens. If $G$ is bipartite, then $L(G)$ and $Q(G)$ share the same spectrum! See Proposition 12.7 in [this book](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OeLI7bxakofXgmv6n0zXPp_EkfP56-ug/view?usp=sharing) to read more about this. One nice result of this is that if $G$ is bipartite, we can use the product of the non-zero eigenvalues of $Q(G)$ to say things about the number of spanning trees of $G$ by applying the [Matrix Tree Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_theorem). See the proof of Theorem 2.7 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.03493) for an example of this result being used in practice.